# Aggregation between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I have the below query where I'm trying to calculate sum of salaries for over a period of year..

```
select sum(case when date_key between to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm')
                                  and to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12), 'yyyymm')
                then salary end) as annual_salary 
from employee
group by emp_key
```

When I execute the query I'm getting null's in the result set..

I actually have valid figures for salaries in employee table.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: It's your `BETWEEN` condition in the `CASE` statement. You're asking for "between now and 12 months ago" (between max and min); you need to ask for "between 12 months ago and now" (between min and max).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(case when date_key between 
                                   to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12), 'yyyymm') and to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm')
                then salary end) as annual_salary 
from employee
group by emp_key
```

Answer (score 2):

Just invert the 2 bounds, they are not in the correct order:

```
...
between to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12), 'yyyymm')
   and to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
sum(case when date_key between to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm') and to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12),'yyyymm') then salary else 0 end) as annual_salary 
from employee group by emp_key
```

CASE WHEN  THEN expr1 ELSE expr2 END
if you don't have "ELSE expr2" Oracle thinks it's NULL